# Google Sheets - Extract number from within quotes (ot first quotes)

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, split, textjoin

I am using join & import data in a google sheet to import some changable text from a website URL.

Like this;

=join(",",importdata("https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=231747"))

The text comes into a single cell, which is correct.

{"231747":{"prices":{"xbox":{"LCPrice":"1,170,000",LCPrice2:"1,172,000",LCPrice3:"1,174,000",LCPrice4:"1,175,000",LCPrice5:"1,185,000",updated:"25 secs ago",MinPrice:"138,000",MaxPrice:"2,600,000",PRP:"41"}

What I want to do is ONLY leave the number from within 5th set of quotation marks.  In the above example the number I would want to extract is 1,170,000

Does anyone know how I would modify my formula above, in order to only leave the number within the 5th set of quotation marks?

Thanks guys for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=--SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(",", IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=231747")), 
 "LCPrice"":""(.*)"), CHAR(34))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  when I try that I get an error;

Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "LCPrice:"(.*)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "{"231747":{"prices":{"xbox":{"LCPrice":"1,174,000",LCPrice2:"1,177,000",LCPrice3:"1,178,000",LCPrice4:"1,179,000",LCPrice5:"1,180,000",updated:"14 mins ago",MinPrice:"138,000",MaxPric

Comment: @hamd01 answer updated